# Problem with Uploading file from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

long ago I posted a question on the stack in which I asked for help with a drag & drop area that I had to put in my project ..
Now I'm here to ask you why once loaded a file of any kind does not let me open the latter giving me this error:

[image]

The upload function works perfectly! but it does not give me permission to open the uploaded file

Below I am attaching my script ...

Ajax.php

```html
<?php
/*$arr_file_types = ['image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg',"document/pdf","file/txt"];

if (!(in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $arr_file_types))) {
 echo "false";
 return;
}*/
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
$date = date('Y-m-d');
if (!file_exists('uploads')) {
 mkdir('uploads', 0777);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$date."_".$_FILES['file']['name']);

echo "File uploaded successfully.";
?>
```

index.php

```css
<style>

    #drop_file_zone {

        background-color: #37bf00;

        border: #999 5px ;

        width: 150px;

        height: 150px;

        padding: 8px;

        font-size: 13px;
    }

    #drag_upload_file {

        width:50%;

        margin:0 auto;

    }

    #drag_upload_file p {

        text-align: center;

    }

    #drag_upload_file #selectfile {

        display: none;

    }
 
 .coloreTdDrop{
  background-color: #37bf00;
 }

</style>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File"  class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
</body>
</html>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var fileobj;
 function upload_file(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fileobj = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
 }

 function file_explorer() {
  document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
  document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
      fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[0];
   ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
  };
 }

 function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
  if(file_obj != undefined) {
      var form_data = new FormData();                  
      form_data.append('file', file_obj);
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    success:function(response) {
     alert(response);
     $('#selectfile').val('');
    }
   });
  }
 }
</script>
```

EDIT : It happen when i try to add the permission to users ...  [Second Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMhxY.png)

Comment: Try using "chmod" for updating the permission of uploaded file in your php function.

Comment: @zipkundan chmod 777 ?

Comment: ^ That could work, I'd start by debugging your directory permissions in Windows (Explorer -> Right Click -> Properties -> Security... [see this guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7)). Once you set permissions on the main directory, should be fine. `0777` like you're doing, is correct. Not sure why you're having issues there.

Comment: @ShengSlogar look at my edit .. it happen when i try to give the permission .

Comment: I think 755 for files should also work.